# my css psedo content not work properly

Tags: css

i want to replace html text to fontawesome icon. normally i do :after and :before but in this case my code not working. no idea why. guys can see what wrong there.  bellow is code

**html**

```
<td><a class="em-calnav em-calnav-prev" href="?ajaxCalendar=1&amp;mo=6&amp;yr=2014&amp;limit=3" rel="nofollow">&lt;&lt;</a></td>
```

**css**

```
a.em-calnav.em-calnav-prev {display:none;}  
a.em-calnav.em-calnav-prev:after {content:'test'; 
  visibility: visible;
  display: block; }
```

demo http://jsfiddle.net/9x4Hg/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set an element with `display:none` - this applies to it's pseudo elements as well.

That's why your code is not working.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/g9Yhe/1/)**

Edit:

Instead of `display:none` on the element, you could use `visibility:hidden`

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/g9Yhe/3/)**

Comment: if i don't set display:none then it will show not replace. i checked your demo also not work. i just show blank. and if you remove display: none then hello and world show both. i want to hello replace to world

Comment: That's right! - That's exactly what I wanted to demonstrate! - You can't set `display:none` on an element and expect to see it's generated content

Comment: yes that i understand.. so how can i replace that then. i tried on jquery. it replace but is it one calender script for wp. so when i click next/previous. its month change without page refresh. when it month that time jquery can not replace that again.